# kdeconnectd crashed with SIGABRT in QMessageLogger::fatal()

Tags: 20.04, kde-connect

Since a few days I got an error after startup:

```
Sorry, Ubuntu 20.04 has experienced an internal error
ExecutablePath
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kdeconnectd
ProblemType
    Crash
Title
    kdeconnectd crashed with SIGABRT in QMessageLogger::fatal()
...
```

Is there a way to fix this problem? If you need any additional information feel free to ask!

EDIT: Output of the system-log as requested

```
20:41:59 sudo:   ludwig : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ludwig ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt install kdeconnect
20:25:00 dbus-daemon: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/modules/kwalletd5" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name="org.kde.kwalletd5" pid=3905 label="snap.chromium.chromium"
20:24:48 kdeconnectd: kdeconnect.core: Broadcasting identity packet
20:23:42 udisksd: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plugin
```

```
20:41:59 sudo:   ludwig : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ludwig ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt install kdeconnect
20:41:02 sudo:   ludwig : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ludwig ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt purge kdeconnect
20:40:50 sudo:   ludwig : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ludwig ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt purge indicator-kdeconnect kdeconnect
20:40:32 sudo:   ludwig : 1 incorrect password attempt ; TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ludwig ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt purge kdeconnect
20:24:48 kdeconnectd: kdeconnect.core: Broadcasting identity packet
20:24:48 kdeconnectd: kdeconnect.core: Broadcasting identity packet
20:24:48 kdeconnectd: kdeconnect.core: Daemon started
20:24:48 kdeconnectd: kdeconnect.core: LanLinkProvider started
20:24:48 kdeconnectd: kdeconnect.core: Daemon starting
20:24:48 kdeconnectd: QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
20:24:48 kdeconnectd: Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
```

Comment: It seems like a bug . I haven't seen such a problem and also a bug report for it. You can report that bug [here](https://bugs.kde.org/) if you want.

Comment: And also the information in the post is quite insufficient. What do you get when you search for the terms **kde** or **kdeconnect** in the system logs ?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi How do I find the system log? If you tell me how to extract the information you need I add it to my question.

Comment: From the post it's clear you're using ubuntu . So go open your terminal and type **gnome-logs** and then search for **kde** or **kdeconnect**.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I added the requested information

Comment: I don't see any suspicious logs in the message you posted.And just recently I found a bug report for it [in launchpad bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdeconnect-plasma/+bug/1732290).It's for ubuntu 17.10 and there's a more complete error message for it.But it's still unsolved.However I think it's a bug.I cannot find any explanation for it.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi So should I leave it as it is?

Comment: Are you using Wayland? If so have you tried it with X11 ? If you are able to use it as it's clear from your logs **Broadcasting identity packet** there's no problem.You can ignore it.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Honestly I don't know what Wayland, X11  and Broadcasting identity packet is

Comment: Never mind.If KDEConnect just works without any problem , just ignore the message.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Thanks a lot :)